# Is there an efficient way to update data from one sheet to another with a match of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that has a main tab and a data tab. I update the data tab daily by copying from a daily report I get automatically from a reporting portal. I dump that data into the data tab and have written some code to update some of the columns in the main tab. The code matches the loan number in column C, if  a match is found it executes the copy and paste.
The code works perfectly but it is slow as I've added other columns to copy.
I am asking the experts to review my code and maybe show me a more efficient way of writing the code so it can run faster. The data it is searching through is only a couple of hundred rows, I don't think it should take too long.
Here is my code:

```
Sub Update_Data()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Mortgage1"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim stNow As Date
Dim sourceRng As Range
Dim destRng As Range
stNow = Now
lrowloans = Worksheets("Main").Range("A6").End(xlDown).Row
lrowdata = Worksheets("Data").Range("C11").End(xlDown).Row
Set sourceRng = Worksheets("Main").Range("A6:A" & lrowloans)
Set destRng = Worksheets("Data").Range("C11:C" & lrowdata)
    Dim match As Boolean
    For Each sRng In sourceRng
If sRng.Value <> "" Then
   With destRng
     Set dRng = .Find(What:=sRng.Value, After:=Worksheets("Data").Range("C11"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
     If Not dRng Is Nothing Then
         Set pasteRng = Worksheets("Main").Range("E" & sRng.Row)
         Set copyRng = Worksheets("Data").Range("G" & dRng.Row & ":H" & dRng.Row)
         copyRng.Copy pasteRng
         Set pasteRng = Worksheets("Main").Range("B" & sRng.Row)
         Set copyRng = Worksheets("Data").Range("D" & dRng.Row & ":E" & dRng.Row)
         copyRng.Copy pasteRng
         Set pasteRng = Worksheets("Main").Range("D" & sRng.Row)
         Set copyRng = Worksheets("Data").Range("U" & dRng.Row & ":U" & dRng.Row)
         copyRng.Copy pasteRng
         Set pasteRng = Worksheets("Main").Range("M" & sRng.Row)
         Set copyRng = Worksheets("Data").Range("Q" & dRng.Row & ":Q" & dRng.Row)
         copyRng.Copy pasteRng
         Set pasteRng = Worksheets("Main").Range("K" & sRng.Row)
         Set copyRng = Worksheets("Data").Range("AP" & dRng.Row & ":AP" & dRng.Row)
         copyRng.Copy pasteRng
         Set pasteRng = Worksheets("Main").Range("N" & sRng.Row)
         Set copyRng = Worksheets("Data").Range("AW" & dRng.Row & ":AW" & dRng.Row)
         copyRng.Copy pasteRng
     End If
   End With
End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Mortgage1"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This will run just about as fast as your computer can do the job. Any difference is achieved by reading from the sheets less frequently. I didn't find any significant sources for delay in your code, such as avoidable loops.

```
Option Explicit

' the assigned numbers are Excel's column numbers
' Test: Debug.Print Columns(NmcName).Address(0,0)

Enum Ndc                ' "Data" columns enumeration
    ' 132 - 08 Dec 2020
    NdcName = 4         ' 4 = column D
    NdcProc             ' "Processor"
    NdcPurp = 7         ' "Purpose"
    NdcProd             ' "Product type"
    NdcLockX = 17       ' "Lock Expiry"
    NdcLoan = 21        ' "Loan amount"
    NdcCD = 42          ' "CD issued"
    NdcClose = 49       ' "Closing date"
End Enum

Enum Nmc                ' "Main" columns
    ' 132 - 08 Dec 2020
    NmcName = 2         ' 2 = column B
    NmcProc             ' "Processor"
    NmcLoan             ' "Loan amount"
    NmcPurp             ' "Purpose"
    NmcProd             ' "Product type"
    NmcCD = 11          ' "CD issued"
    NmcLockX = 13       ' "Lock Expiry"
    NmcClose            ' "Closing date"
End Enum


Sub Update_Data()
    ' 132 - 08 Dec 2020
    
    Const pWord         As String = "Mortgage1"
    
    Dim WsMain          As Worksheet
    Dim WsData          As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRng       As Range
    Dim destRng         As Range
    Dim sCell           As Range                    ' loop object
    Dim Fnd             As Range                    ' cell found by Find
    Dim SrcArr          As Variant                  ' data from Fnd.Row
    Dim SrcClm          As Variant                  ' array of source columns
    Dim DstClm          As Variant                  ' array of destination columns
    Dim C               As Long                     ' loop counter: column
    
    Set WsMain = Worksheets("Main")
    Set WsData = Worksheets("Data")
    
    With WsMain
        .Unprotect Password:=pWord            ' presuming WsMain is your AciveSheet
        Set sourceRng = .Range(.Cells(6, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With
    With WsData
        Set destRng = .Range(.Cells(11, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    ' data will be copied from SrcClm to DstClm, like NdcPurp to NmcPurp
    ' sequence is immaterial but position must match
    ' number of columns in both arrays must be identical
    ' effect modifications in the Enum
    SrcClm = Array(NdcPurp, NdcProd, NdcName, NdcProc, NdcLoan, NdcLockX, NdcCD, NdcClose)
    DstClm = Array(NmcPurp, NmcProd, NmcName, NmcProc, NmcLoan, NmcLockX, NmcCD, NmcClose)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sCell In sourceRng
        If sCell.Value <> "" Then
            With destRng
                Set Fnd = .Find(What:=sCell.Value, _
                                After:=.Cells(1), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False, _
                                SearchFormat:=False)
                If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
                    SrcArr = .Range(.Cells(Fnd.Row, 1), .Cells(Fnd.Row, NdcClose)).Value
                    For C = LBound(SrcClm) To UBound(SrcClm)
                        WsMain.Cells(sCell.Row, DstClm(C)).Value = SrcArr(1, SrcClm(C))
                    Next C
                End If
           End With
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    WsMain.Protect Password:=pWord
End Sub
```

The code's syntax has been tested but, for lack of data, not its functionality. Especially the coordination of enumerations *Ndc* and *Nmc* with the arrays *SrcClm* and *DstClm* may write some values to the wrong columns. Here's how you can fix that. Look for these two arrays.

```
SrcClm = Array(NdcPurp, NdcProd, NdcName, NdcProc, NdcLoan, NdcLockX, NdcCD, NdcClose)
DstClm = Array(NmcPurp, NmcProd, NmcName, NmcProc, NmcLoan, NmcLockX, NmcCD, NmcClose)
```

`SrcClm` lists all used columns in the source sheet. `DstClm` lists all used columns in the destination sheet. You can add, delete or change either. The sequence is immaterial. But for every Source cell there must be a destination cell. Therefore the number of columns in both arrays must always be the same.

The arrays specify columns. The rows will be found by the code. The Source row is determined one after the other, in a loop. The Destination row is `Fnd.Row`. Now the code works through the two arrays. It takes the first column from `SrcClm`, finds the cell with the help of the provided row and pastes it to the first column from the `DstClm` array in the Fnd.Row row.

Example:- The first `SrcClm` is *NdcG* which was given a value of 7 (column G) in the enumeration. The first `DstClm`is *NmcE* which has a value of 5 (column E) in the enumeration. Now, presume instead of reading from column G you wanted to read from column H. So you start from the Enumeration. Change the assigned value from 7 to 8. Note that this change would automatically also change the value of *NdcH*. This is because NdcH as no value assigned to it which VBA understands to mean "next number". So, when you change *NdcG* to , *NdcH* will become 9 and you may have to change that, too.

After you change the value of *NdcG* the code will read from column H, just as you wanted, but the enumeration's name is wrong. Had we given descriptive names to the enumerations, like *NdcName, NdcDob* and *NdcContractID* this problem wouldn't exist. But as it is now *NdcG* must be changed to *NdcH* and you can't do that before you change the existing *NdcH* to *NdcI*.

Anyway, don't change the name in the enumeration. Instead, use *Edit > Replace* and replace all occurrences of NdcH with NdcI and, thereafter, all occurrences of NdcG to NdcH. All of this sounds complicated and it is that. You need to give your full attention to avoid mistakes.

Of course, in this way you can change any source or destination column in the system. It's not difficult and can be completed quite fast after you have done it once.

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me where I should place the Enum code, I am not an expert and it doesn't work when I just paste it into the VBA editor. Is there something else that I have to use for the Enum code?

Comment: I figured out that I had to place the enum code in the declarations section so that is working. The code works much faster than mine, thanks. The problem is that the I can't figure out how to manipulate the columns so they are pasting the data in the wrong columns. The sheets do not have the same amount of columns and they are not in the same order, is this a requirement?

Comment: Ok after more testing and studying the code I think the problem is that in the source sheet the field I am trying to match (loan number) is in column C and the destination sheet has the loan number field in column A but I have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: Enums must be at the top of a code sheet, before any procedures. Any code sheet will do but for for enums that aren't `Private` it's best to use a standard code module. I shall address your other request through an amendment to my above answer.

Comment: I have tried for a couple of hours and and although your explanation is very detailed I just can't make it work. I need D (name) from the Data Sheet to paste to B of the main sheet, E (processor) from Data sheet  to C of the main sheet, U (loan amount) from Data sheet  to D of the main sheet, G (purpose) from Data sheet  to E of the main sheet, H (product type) from Data sheet  to F of the main sheet,  AP (CD Issued) from Data sheet  to K of the main sheet, Q (lock expiration) from Data sheet  to M of the main sheet, and AW (closing date) from Data sheet  to N of the main sheet

Comment: I've modified the enumeration names in my answer above. As you see, the columns are now visibly correct in arrays `SrcClm` and`DstClm`. To move a source or destination just change the column numbers in the enums.

Comment: However, previous differences should still persist. The likely reason is a mix-up between source and destination. You will find it by eliminating the confusion in the variable names. You call the tabs "Data" and "Main" but thereafter the talk is entirely of "Src" and "Dst". If you use one way of naming you will stumble on the error. In this kind of error all data will be picked and posted wrongly. If you have just a single error it must be a column number wrongly assigned to one of the enumerations.

Comment: I appreciate your persistence :-)  However, the result is the same as the previous code. For NdcName it is copying column H instead of Column D onto NmcName column 2 in the Main Sheet, and the rest are also not copying the correct columns.The root of the problem appears to be that the columns are not identical in each sheet and therefore are not mapping correctly. Unfortunately I cannot alter them.

Comment: As I told you, if all columns are wrong the cause is a swap of source and destination. This could be at range level or at worksheet level. You will find it if you apply consistent naming to the respective variables and then common sense. Almost no programming knowledge required. You only need to know if "Data" is the "Source" or "Destination" and then make sure that "Main" doesn't take its place.

Comment: I think this is wrong, no matter what I do I am an unable to get the mappring right. I think that because the 2 sheets are not setup the same way from a column point of view the mapping is out of whack. The code thinks that column 1 is column E (5) not column A in Data tab so when I try to map NdcName to NmcName it copies over the data from column E in the Data tab to Column B in the main tab

Comment: The code doesn't think. Via Enums and the two arrays you have full control, free to assign any column to any other column. If you want to map E to A you can do it. I suspect mixup between sheets. If you upload your workbook somewhere and post the link here I'll look at it and return the workbook in the same way.